# PyKEP python keplerian toolbox

Tags: python, module

I followed the instructions on installing the keplerian toolbox for python and everything went fine but there is an issue when trying to import the modules.

Instructions I followed: [keptoolbox](http://keptoolbox.sourceforge.net/system.html)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import core, sims_flanagan
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/core/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from _core import *
ImportError: libkeplerian_toolbox.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file `libkeplerian_toolbox.so` is in `/usr/local/lib/libkeplerian_toolbox.so`.  Do I need to copy somewhere else?

Everything installed in the correct directory though:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libkeplerian_toolbox.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/core/_core.so
-- Removed runtime path from "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/core/_core.so"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/core/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/sims_flanagan/_sims_flanagan.so
-- Removed runtime path from "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/sims_flanagan/_sims_flanagan.so"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/sims_flanagan/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/orbit_plots/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/orbit_plots/_plots.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/examples/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/examples/_ex1.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/examples/_ex2.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/examples/_ex3.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/examples/_ex4.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/examples/_ex5.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/interplanetary/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKEP/interplanetary/_mga_1dsm.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linking problem, `ldconfig` does not look in `/usr/local/lib` by default, so you need to add it to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` (just put it under the include statement).
Now run

```
ldconfig
```

and the error should be gone.